# RegEx Trouble with Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to create an expression that removes all links in an HTML file and replaces their destination with "#".

Find:

```
<a href="."$ `
```

Replace:

```
<a href="#"
```

But Notepad++ says 0 results.

Here is an excerpt from my source file - http://pastebin.com/aDa3HTcb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot matches a single character, and you anchor your regex at the end of the input (`$`), it is therefore expected.

Replace your initial regex with:

```
<a href="[^"]+"
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In your find your regex is malformated.

Try with a regex like :

```
<a href="[^"]*"
```